# Await for a svelte store value to be true then call for data (TS)

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, svelte

I have a pop up prompt asking for a users year group, as I have databases for each year group I would like to call a function after the value of `userInfo` changed to `true`.

My JS knowledge is quite elementary and I have only dealt with async calls and promises in the contexts of API fetching. What I have right now is.

example:

```js
onMount(async function check() {
        // check if user has entered thieir information
        if ($userInfo) {
            getYearGroupSchedule($yeargroup, weekdates);
        } else {
            // await for userinfo to be true
        }
    });
```

I don't know if this the right way to approach it but I am very lost and would like some help please. If there is any clarifying questions needed please comment bellow.

Answer (score 0):

Logic in `onMount` is only executed once. If you want to wait for a condition, you probably would want to use a [reactive statement](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive):

```js
$: if ($userInfo) {
    getYearGroupSchedule($yeargroup, weekdates);
}
```

This will get checked and executed whenever a dependency changes, note that this will take all used variables into account (in this case including `$yeargroup` and `weekdates`). If you only want to trigger on a specific condition, call a function and thus "hide" the other variables. E.g.

```js
$: if ($userInfo) update();
```